# Caching of HTML template in Polymer

Tags: caching, polymer

Does anyone know how to cache html between routes in polymer. I am not referring to offline caching here.I am a novice in Polymer, any help is greatly appreciated.

For example, If while I am in template A I make some operations and show few data on the UI as a result of those operations, then I go to template B, if I come to template A again the entire UI is refreshed and the previous data is not shown on UI. How do I stop this from happening.

In angular for instance we set cache:true in routes to retain the page contents. I am looking for something in similar to that.

Comment: Ashish Kamble: I have edited, hope this gives more clarity. I did search before posting, however I could not get a proper solution. Hence posted.

Comment: @MaliniRam Polymer is a library to help you write web components and it aims to help us until native support exists in all the browsers.. so it's a set of polyfills and some light helpers.. not a framework to give you a set of powerful tools and out of the box features.. so it is up to you to implement a strategy not to refresh data that often.. for example you could use it with redux as state container and have your source of data and decision where to refresh it there..

Comment: @MaliniRam Post some of your code so we can see the exact cause of your problem. Could be related to storage, routing, or something else entirely.

Comment: @mishu and AmmoPT : Thanks a lot for the revert. I understood that I have to put some logic in for what I am looking for, unlike in other powerful framework like Angular